# How to load image asynchronously and then show it in react-cropper? My problem is handling the loading process

Tags: reactjs, image, cropperjs

How can I handle the loading process of my image, and then use that in react cropper(cropper.js integration into React). https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cropper. My problem is to handle the image loading process and show some spinner while image is loading, and after to show the cropper component.
Here is my code.
https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-sunset-3v3me

Comment: please add some code so people don't have to assume your implementation

Comment: @van I just added